# Selecting first record per value in a field

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm trying to build a kind of "fuzzy logic" system in Access.

Essentially I have a set of data, one of the fields is "Provider" but the way the data is entered at source the "Provider" can be hidden in other text, or be abbreviated.

I have another table of all the different text strings I have identified and which Provider they actually are.

So for example the Provider "Flynet" may be entered as

- flynet
- fame flynet
- flynet.com
- FameFlynet.uk.com
- fame
- etc

So far I have got to the point where I can get a table of data that pulls through the normalised Provider, or if there isn't a match on those keywords I've identified, then it brings through the original value in the Provider field.

However it will bring back multiple records if it matches more than one of the keywords in the Provider text, i.e. a record entered as fameflynet will be picked up by the "flynet" and "fame" keywords and appear twice.

How do I limit it so that I only get 1 record returned per record in the raw data?

I'm currently using 2 queries to get to where I am.

```
SELECT [Weekly Data].ID, Keywords.Return
FROM Keywords, [Weekly Data]
WHERE ((([Weekly Data].Provider) Like "*" & [keywords].[lookup] & "*"));
```

And then

```
SELECT [Weekly Data].ID, IIf([Q_Key_Search]![Return]<>"",[Q_Key_Search]![Return],[Weekly Data]![Provider]) AS Act_Provider
FROM [Weekly Data] LEFT JOIN Q_Key_Search ON [Weekly Data].ID = Q_Key_Search.ID;
```

Comment: Have you tried SELECT DISTINCT ?

Comment: I did thanks, but couldn't get that to work.

Answer (score 0):

I have got there, but I'm using 4 Queries....

The first checks if there is a match on Keywords.

Q_Key_Search

```
SELECT [Weekly Data].ID, Keywords.Return
FROM Keywords, [Weekly Data]
WHERE ((([Weekly Data].Provider) Like "*" & [keywords].[lookup] & "*"));
```

The second then brings back either the normalised provider if i found a match, or the original value if not.

Q_Consol

```
SELECT [Weekly Data].ID, IIf([Q_Key_Search]![Return]<>"",[Q_Key_Search]![Return],[Weekly Data]![Provider]) AS Act_Provider
FROM [Weekly Data] LEFT JOIN Q_Key_Search ON [Weekly Data].ID = Q_Key_Search.ID;
```

The third then gets rid of duplicates, bringing back the first value in the consolidated provider field.

Q_Dedupe

```
SELECT Q_Consol.ID, First(Q_Consol.Act_Provider) AS FirstOfAct_Provider
FROM Q_Consol
GROUP BY Q_Consol.ID;
```

The fourth is the end result, how many records per normalised provider.

Q_Count

```
SELECT Count(Q_Dedupe.ID) AS CountOfID, Q_Dedupe.FirstOfAct_Provider
FROM Q_Dedupe
GROUP BY Q_Dedupe.FirstOfAct_Provider
ORDER BY Count(Q_Dedupe.ID) DESC;
```

I'm sure there's a more elegant solution but it works....